# Ember computed property on a controller not bound in template

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript

I'm trying to implement a password strength checker that will update on every key press. My template looks like this:

```
{{input type="password" id="password" value=password }}
```

My controller looks like this:

```
App.SignupController = Ember.Controller.extend
  passwordStrength: ((key,val) ->
    # check strength if val is defined
    return
  ).property('password')
```

`passwordStrength` is never called when text is entered in the field.

*However*, if I rename the method to just `password` and remove the computed property's name, it does work:

```
App.SignupController = Ember.Controller.extend
  password: ((key,val) ->
    # check strength if val is defined
    return
  ).property()
```

I'd rather understand why the former was not working though, and use a more sensibly named method too.

Comment: what do you want to do with the passwordStrength property ?, are you going to use it to show a warning message ?. Why don't you change passwordStrength to be an observer ?, an observer fires as soon as one of the observed properties change, maybe name the observer different, like checkPasswordStrength, and there, set a isPassWordStrong property, and use that property in your template.

Comment: fanta I've basically just put your comment into an answer and created a jsbin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a jsbin for you to look at that is working and updating when the password is updated.  I think I know why this is not working for you.  in my js bin here http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gekofo/4/edit?html,js,console,output  You will notice that only the observer console.logs.  Whereas in your program I would imagine you maybe aren't displaying the passwordStrength value.  If you add {{passwordStrength}} into the template in my bin, you will see that the property gets updated.  So it looks like you may want to use the passwordStrength2 that i have written, because it will update whether it is displayed in the DOM or not.

In short use this:

```
passwordStrength2: function() {
   //check strength if val is defined
   console.log("OBSERVER::", this.get('password.length'))
   return this.get('password.length');
}.observes('password')
```

NOT:

```
passwordStrength: function() {
  //check strength if val is defined
  console.log("PROPERTY::", this.get('password.length'))
  return this.get('password.length');
}.property('password')
```

Also I do not know coffeescript, so sorry my answer is in javascript.

Comment: This lead me down the right track. In my template I set `value=password` and used `observes('password')` in my controller to do what I want. Thanks for help!